# Centering horizontal unordered list without it having a fixed width

Tags: css, list, centering

I often want to horizontally center an horizontal menu (an unordered list with the `li` elements floated) without specifyling a fixed width, so that the menu remains centered in all resolutions.

To my knowledge there's no way to achieve that, but perhaps there is some little know trick to achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203910/css-horizontal-menu-equally-spaced OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082067/css-dynamic-horizontal-navigation-menu-to-fill-up-specific-width-table-behavior OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't this do the trick?

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/8njmykff/)**